# How to configure a view in SCOM not to show alerts in maintenance mode?

Tags: scom

We currently use SCOM 2007 for monitoring our Unix servers. Sometimes we have a large number of alerts that we are working on, so we put these alerts in maintenance mode.

We would like to have them removed from our primary view, because it clutters the view.

We currently have 1 view with all alerts, but we want to have 2 views:

- A view with all alerts, but not the ones in maintenance mode
- A view with all alerts and also the ones in maintenance mode

The first view will be the view we will use to see if anything new happened, so it sould not be cluttered with alerts in maintenance mode.

When I right-click the view and click properties, I see a list of conditions, but none of them allows me to filter out alerts in maintenance mode.